# Is there a way to call mysql query from WebdriverIO/Mocha/Javascript frmaework test case?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Not able to call sql query from it block
Not even executed db.query statement but simply test passed

**Here is the code block **

```
var db = require("../utils/db");

it("DB Testing", () => {
 db.query('SELECT type FROM docket.story_types where id="4"', function(error, results){
console.log("DB Results +results[0].types);
 })
console.log("testing end")
})
```

Note: **database connection established successfully but the line inside it block (db.query...) is not getting executed. Anyone have any idea how to call query from here**